# How can I fetch the results from the first and last row of each partition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I can't figure out how to write an efficient query that merges results with the same identifier and uses information from the first and last result.

I have the following table (Only the trades with a buy and sell action):

| Position | action | symbol | executed_at | price | profit | lot_size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | buy | XAUUSD | 2022-07-05 20:05:49 | 1763.20 | 0 | 0 |
| 1111 | sell | XAUUSD | 2022-07-05 20:08:49 | 1764.20 | 500 | 5 |
| 1111 | sell | XAUUSD | 2022-07-05 20:10:49 | 1765.20 | 1000 | 5 |
| 2222 | sell | XAUUSD | 2022-07-05 20:05:49 | 1400 | 0 | 0 |

This must result in the following table:

| Position | action | symbol | opened_at | closed_at | entry_price | close_price | profit | lot_size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | buy | XAUUSD | 2022-07-05 20:05:49 | 2022-07-05 20:10:49 | 1763.20 | 1765.20 | 1500 | 10 |

The requirements:

- Group by position
- Get the executed_at of the first row as opened_at
- Get the executed_at of the last row as closed_at
- Get the price of the first row as entry_price
- Get the price of the last row as close_price
- Sum of all the positions their profit
- Sum of all the positions their lot_size
- Only show results where a buy AND a sell action is present (or `DISTINCT COUNT(action) = 2`)

I've created the following query and the only thing that is not working is the last requirement (only show results with buy and sell action).

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (position)
    position,
    symbol,
  action,
  first_value(executed_at) OVER w as opened_at,
  last_value(executed_at) OVER w as closed_at,
    first_value(price) OVER w as entry_price,
    last_value(price) OVER w as close_price,
  sum(lot_size) OVER w as lot_size,
    sum(profit) OVER w as profit
FROM deals
WHERE action IN('buy', 'sell')
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY position ORDER BY executed_at ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

Can someone steer me in the right direction? I don't have much experience with window functions and group functions. Also, if the query can be written more efficiently I would like to know.

Comment: Please TAG your specific RDBMS, `window` deifinition syntax is not universally supported

Comment: @Stu thanks, I've added postgresql as the RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use the EXISTS clause in this case, because personally I feel like the logic is easier to follow.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (position)
    position,
    symbol,
  action,
  first_value(executed_at) OVER w as opened_at,
  last_value(executed_at) OVER w as closed_at,
  first_value(price) OVER w as entry_price,
  last_value(price) OVER w as close_price,
  sum(lot_size) OVER w as lot_size,
  sum(profit) OVER w as profit
FROM deals
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deals d2 WHERE action='buy' AND d2.position=deals.position)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deals d2 WHERE action='sell' AND d2.position=deals.position)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY position ORDER BY executed_at ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

If you haven't used them before - just notice that what you select does not matter, it is the join clause that makes the magic happen.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4ba96d/6)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help! This solutions works perfectly! My only concern is the performance with large data sets with the 2 extra subqueries. But the subqueries should be really fast, so maybe it's not a problem.

Comment: yeah, EXISTS is going to scale very well. if it doesn't, just post a new question and focus the question on improving the performance and there are some really good folks out there who can help with that.  But this is probably faster than the alternative which is subqueries with a count distinct.  The slow one to avoid is WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM deals d2 WHERE action='buy')